# amazon alexa skill kit (ASK)

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

what is the difference between `this.emit(:ask)` and `this.response(:speak)` in Amazon Alexa
EG:

```
let handler = {
    'PlayVideoIntent' : function() {

        // VideoApp.Play directives can be added to the response
        if (this.event.context.System.device.supportedInterfaces.VideoApp) {
            this.response.playVideo('http://path/to/my/video.mp4');
        } else {
            this.response.speak("The video cannot be played on your device. " +
                "To watch this video, try launching the skill from your echo show device.");
        }

        this.emit(':responseReady');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Alexa Skills Kit [documentation](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs#alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs) have a detailed explanation.

From [Response vs ResponseBuilder](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs#response-vs-responsebuilder) section:

> Currently, there are two ways to generate the response objects in Node.js SDK. The first way is using the syntax follows the format `this.emit(:${action}, 'responseContent')`.
>
> If you want to manually create your own responses, you can use `this.response` to help. `this.response` contains a series of functions, that you can use to set the different properties of the response. This allows you to take advantage of the Alexa Skills Kit's built-in audio and video player support. Once you've set up your response, you can just call `this.emit(':responseReady')` to send your response to Alexa. The functions within `this.response` are also chainable, so you can use as many as you want in a row.
>
> When you have finished set up your response, simply call `this.emit(':responseReady')` to send your response off. Below are two examples that build response with several response objects:
>
> Example1:
>
> `this.response.speak(speechOutput)
>               .listen(repromptSpeech);
>   this.emit(':responseReady');`
>
> Example 2
>
> `this.response.speak(speechOutput)
>               .cardRenderer(cardTitle, cardContent, cardImage)
>               .renderTemplate(template)
>               .hint(hintText, hintType);
>   this.emit(':responseReady');`
>
> Since responseBuilder is more flexible to build rich response objects, we prefer using this method to build the response.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow. The answer is available in the question itself.

When you have an `ask` it essentially means that the session is still maintained and Alexa is expecting something from the user. And on the other hand if you are going with a tell, it means that there is no session available. below example will be helpful.

**tell**

```
User: Alexa, how are you doing.

Alexa: I'm doing good thank you. 

--Conversation ended
```

**ask**

```
User: Alexa set an alarm
Alexa: sure, at what time? <-- This is where we use ask, as the conversation is incomplete
User: at 5:30 AM
Alexa: Alarm set <-- This is where we use tell, as the task is done and there is no use of user's input anymore.
```

Hope this helps you.

Happy Coding!!!